# Aarray value sorting by rating after return

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have one array and I want it to sort of rating means record should be high to low and

**Note: I get the perfect result using this. but I have used pagination also.
When I am at the 1st-page record is already display as I want. but when I go to the 2nd page. it will again sort.**

I want all record are sort and then output should be display.

Thanks.

```
$array[] = array(
     "id"=>$data->id,
     "name" => $data->name,
     "delivery_time" => $data->delivery_time,
     "currency" => $data->currency,
     "image" => $data->photo,
     "lat" => $data->lat,
     "lon" => $data->lon,
     "Category" => $category,
     "ratting" => $ratting,
     "res_status" => $openclose,
     "distance"=>$data->distance,
     "distancekm" => "$km",
     "open_time"=>$data->open_time,
     "close_time"=>$data->close_time
 );
 if ($_GET['short_by'] == 'ratting') {
     usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
          return $a['ratting'] < $b['ratting'];
     });
     return $array;
 }
```

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. What is 2nd page? Where do you set/paginate?

Comment: actually this is use in web service above array is for web service response. from android side every time 5 record should be load .. after scroll down again 5 record.. that's it

Comment: still: right now we have an array that gets sorted. We see the part that is working, not the part that isn't.

Comment: yes.....but.....show the code!! We can't fix a problem if we can't see the problem.

Comment: Yes.. it is working perfect .. what is problem 
for ex.: if we have 10 record 
record rating is 
1->5 , 2->4 , 3->3 , 4->2 , 5->1 , 6->5 , 7->4 , 8->3 , 9->2 , 10->1
in first page  we can see 5 record 
1->5 , 2->4 , 3->3 , 4->2 , 5->1
in second page it will again sort by rating like
 6->5 , 2->4 , 8->3 , 9->2 , 10->1

correct result should be :
in first page
 1->5 , 6->5 , 2->4 ,  7->4 , 3->3 

In second page :
8->3 , 4->2 , 9->2 , 5->1 , 10->1